# can i allow an android activity to change to landscape only on certain conditions?

Tags: android, conditional-statements, rotation

most of my application will not look so well on landscape, but that's the user choice as far as i'm concerned if to see the application on 'wide' screen.
However i have an auto complete screen and that screen cannot function in landscape mode since when user input text and i bring the results into the list view on screen the user can't see the listview since the virtual keyboard covers it all.
So i thought of defining in the manifest that this activity wont be used in landscape, but i CAN use it in landscape mode for devices with hardware keyboard that is open...

So either i can define it in the manifest (couldn't find how) or i need to do it melodramatically (discover the keyboard existence and open to support it, or disable the rotation otherwise).

Anyone knows how to do that ?:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

OR

activity android:name=".SomeActivity" 
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"

these may help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can also intercept these config changes:

```
<activity ...
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
</activity>
```

and in `onConfigurationChanged()` you can decide what to do with them.

Comment: that will only let me handle the orientation myself, which i don't really want to, in addition it doesn't let me choose if to change the orientation or not it just lets me know that orientation change has happen.

Comment: but if you want to change the orientation only when the keyboard exists and is out, you'll have to use it. if inside it you do nothing (say when orientation changed, but there's no keyboard), the change will just be ignored.